# How to write a pyspark-dataframe to redshift?

Tags: pyspark, spark-avro, spark-redshift

I am trying to write a pyspark DataFrame to Redshift but it results into error:-

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.sql.avro.AvroFileFormat could not be instantiated

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat.$init$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat;)V

Spark Version: 2.4.1

Spark-submit command: spark-submit --master local[*] --jars ~/Downloads/spark-avro_2.12-2.4.0.jar,~/Downloads/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar,~/Downloads/RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.20.1043.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar,~/Downloads/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.3,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.0 script.py

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *

import sys
import os

pe_dl_dbname            = os.environ.get("REDSHIFT_DL_DBNAME")
pe_dl_host              = os.environ.get("REDSHIFT_DL_HOST")
pe_dl_port              = os.environ.get("REDSHIFT_DL_PORT")
pe_dl_user              = os.environ.get("REDSHIFT_DL_USER")
pe_dl_password          = os.environ.get("REDSHIFT_DL_PASSWORD")

s3_bucket_path = "s3-bucket-name/sub-folder/sub-sub-folder"
tempdir = "s3a://{}".format(s3_bucket_path)

driver = "com.databricks.spark.redshift"
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")

datalake_jdbc_url = 'jdbc:redshift://{}:{}/{}?user={}&password={}'.format(pe_dl_host, pe_dl_port, pe_dl_dbname, pe_dl_user, pe_dl_password)

"""
The table is created in Redshift as follows:
create table adhoc_analytics.testing (name varchar(255), age integer);
"""
l = [('Alice', 1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['name', 'age'])
df.show()
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", datalake_jdbc_url) \
  .option("dbtable", "adhoc_analytics.testing") \
  .option("tempdir", tempdir) \
  .option("tempformat", "CSV") \
  .save()
```

Comment: If you have a rather large file, it's also best to split it up into smaller parts that correspond to your Redshift cluster's size, so that you can take advantage of Redshift's parallel processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks Spark-Redshift doesn't work with Spark version 2.4.1,
Here is the version that I maintain to make it work with Spark 2.4.1
https://github.com/goibibo/spark-redshift

How to use it:

> pyspark --packages "com.github.goibibo:spark-redshift:v4.1.0" --repositories "https://jitpack.io"